# How to manually corrupt the Oracle CLOB data

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, clob, corruption

I'm wondering if there's any way to manually corrupt the CLOB data for testing purpose.

I can find the [steps for intensional block corruption](https://smarttechways.com/2017/04/07/manually-create-corruption-in-oracle-datafile/), but can't find anything for the individual data in a table. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is what I'm trying to do and I need help for step 1:

1. Prepare the corrupted CLOB data
2. Run expdb and get ORA-01555 error
3. Test if my troubleshooting procedure works ok

Some background:

- DB: Oracle 12.2.0.1 SE2
- OS: Windows Server 2016
- The app we're using (from the 3rd party) seems to occasionally corrupt the CLOB data when a certain type of data gets inserted in a table. We don't know what triggers it. The corruption doesn't affect the app's function, but leaving it unfixed gives the following error when running expdb for daily backup:

  `ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number`
- CLOB consists of a mix of alphanumeric characters and line breaks. It gets inserted by the app, no manual insert takes place
- Fixing/replacing the app isn't an option, so we've got a fixing procedure with us.
- I took over this from another engineer (who's left already), but since then the app is happily working and no problem has occurred so far. I want to test run the fixing procedure in DEV environment, but the app doesn't reproduce the problem for me.
- So I thought if I can manually prepare the "broken" CLOB for testing purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this looks like it is caused by a known bug:

- https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=364607910994084&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=833635.1&id=787004.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=3xr6s00uo_200
- https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=364470181721910&id=846079.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=3xr6s00uo_53
- https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=364481844925661&id=833635.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=3xr6s00uo_102

The main point here is that the corruption isn't caused by anything inherant in the data, but is more likely caused by something like concurrent access to the LOB by multiple updates (application or end-user behavior), or just by apparently random chance. As such, I doubt that there's any way for you to easily force this condition in order to validate your test for it.

Comment: pmdba, thank you for your comment and suggestions. 
Yes, the first thing to check is UNDO tblspace as you've mentioned, however there is a case where the corrupted CLOB is the cause of ORA-01555 ([link](https://dbpilot.net/2018/ora-1555-snapshot-too-old-due-to-corrupted-lobs/)), and I think I'm facing the same problem. Expdb works fine after detecting the CLOB corruption and deleting the corrupted record.
So I want to prepare some kind of corrupted CLOB data, to test the detection & recovery steps myself...any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Few points to add: (1)the app (Tomcat service) is stopped when running expdb, hence there's no transaction happening,(2)modifying the UNDO_RETENTION parameter (to something like 7200 sec) and expanding UNDO tablespace did not solve the issue

Comment: @alt130 I don't think "corrupted" is the right terminology here. One difficulty with LOBs is that their undo information can be stored inside the LOB itself and the LOB settings may need to be adjusted in addition to the system settings. I can't remember all the details, but I think you'll need to look up SecureFiles versus BasicFiles, PCTVERSION, and maybe other settings.

Comment: Reading through the referenced Oracle Support docs, "corrupted" actually is the right terminology. Looks like this is caused by a known bug that's been around in one form or another since Oracle 9. The data itself isn't the problem; it looks like it has more to do with concurrent updates or with automatic segment management in the LOB tablespace. There is some indication that switching to SecureFiles might offer some protection, but no guarantee.

Comment: Jon, pmdba, thank you for the comments and sorry for the late response. I guess it's difficult to intentionally mess up the CLOB itself, might have to give up what I was trying to do. However the SecureFiles vs BasicFiles and other settings are new insights, I'll look them up & check the settings if I can avoid the trouble happening at all (in fact this would be the best solution). Thanks again for your help!!